# Python CGI downloads the file instead of executing on CentOS

Tags: python, centos, cgi

I have worked on CGI by python programming on Ubuntu and I got satisfied result. I have a HTML file that has a simple form with a simple input as button, and an action to `.py` file. the `.py` file has `755` permission and is located in `/var/www/cgi-bin`. and the HTML is located in `/var/www/html`. I run the `CGIHTTPServer` by executing the following command in `/var/www/` directory. But when I click the button, the browser instead of executing the `.py` file, tries to download it and it's annoying me. I tried to reconfigure `http.conf` file with `<Directory></Directory>` tag of `cgi-bin` many times but no result! Please HELP ME!!!!

### show_database.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from MySQLdb import *

# Creates a connection with database
dbconnection = connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="testdb")

# Creates a cursor of db
cursor = dbconnection.cursor()

# Selects data from database
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM inp;")

# HTML view by printing codes as strings
print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("")
print("<html>")

# Body of HTML Page
print("<body>")
print("<h1>بانک اطلاعاتی!</h1>")

# A table that shows the database
print("<table>")
print("<th>ID</th><th>input</th>")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print("<tr>")
    print("<td>" + str(row['ID']) + "</td>")
    print("<td>" + str(row['inpt']) + "</td>")
    print("</tr>")
print("</table>")

# End of HTML
print("</body></html>")
```

### display_database.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<style>
    body { background: #ececec; }
    body, p { text-align: center; direction: rtl; }
</style>
<body>
    <h1>نمای وب‌گونه از بانک اطلاعاتی</h1>
    <p>دکمه زیر را فشار دهید تا بانک اطلاعاتی را مشاهده نمائید!</p>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/show_database.py">
        <input type="Submit" value="مشاهده‌ی بانک" name="data">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the html file like `hhtp://localhost/display_databse.html` ?
Well if its still not working you can try [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org).Its hassle free to setup the same apache server with mariadb/php for home/testing usage but needs some tweaking for production.